# Ubuntu dependencies hell

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get, dpkg, dependencies

```
pippo@pippo-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading the package list... Done
Generation of the dependency three       
Reading state info... Done
Dependents correction... error.
 aspell : Dipends: libaspell15 (= 0.60.6-4ubuntu1) but version 0.60.7~20110707-1.2 is installed
 gcc-4.9-base : Breaks: gcc-4.4-base (< 4.4.7) but version 4.4.4-14ubuntu5.1 is installed
 libc-dev-bin : Dipends: libc6 (< 2.13) but version 2.19-11 is installed
 libc6 : Suggests: libc6-i686
     Breaks: locales (< 2.19) but version 2.13+git20100825-1 is installed
 libc6-dev : Dipends: libc6 (= 2.12.1-0ubuntu10.4) but version 2.19-11 is installed
 libnih1 : Dipends: libc6 (< 2.13) but version 2.19-11 is installed
 libstdc++6 : Breaks: gcc-4.4 (< 4.4.6-4) but versions 4.4.4-14ubuntu5.1 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated some interrupts. This can happen due to the blocked packages.
E: Can not correct the dependents
```

How I can get out of this hell? 
(this happened when I tried to install YAGF from a deb) (yes, I must not install packages that isn't intended for my version, but how I can get rid of this now?)

---

Now my mouse became 'X11 style' and windows title bar is disappeared.
I won't make mistakes like this anymore, so please help an idiot like me to recover my system.

Comment: Add some info about your system, and maybe a link to the package you were installing. In general you can try before to uninstall the pakage that gives problems (maybe with `--purge` option too). After again `apt-get update`, then `apt-get -f install` then if needed `dpkg-reconfigure --all`. Important: cross your fingers. :)

Comment: @Hastur purge LibC? Really?

Comment: No I mean YAGF.